# Is it possible to make a map projection where one area is comically large and in the center, and the north/south has rotated a bit?

Tags: coordinate-system

I am looking to create a humorous world map projection where one location that is about 13 miles long and 3 miles wide is huge and takes up the entire middle of the map, with the rest of the world distorted around it (but still recognizable as the world). I would also like the orientation to rotated counter clockwise about 30 degrees. Is this possible to do?

Comment: In GIS the point of projections is to make the display of geographic data as accurate as possible. Your requirement, while amusing, would be the opposite so nobody would have even considered implementing it. I do think that you could make a map and stretch it in an artistic package like GIMP or PhotoShop, these would also let you cut out some from one side and move it to the other side to centre the map where you want, no easy task in GIS sotware... (I still have traumatic memories of working around the international date line).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a new idea: take a map of said island and then create a globe of it, then create a projection from that. I think it will work!

Comment: You could use a geometry generator style in QGIS and translate the geometries' vertices accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

In Python you could make a [Cartopy](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/index.html) map with the target area in the middle, then you could distort it using something like [implode](https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.0/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.implode) from the "wand" library:

```py
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
from wand.image import Image
from wand.drawing import Drawing

# world with the US in the middle
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.Mercator(central_longitude=-105, min_latitude=-60.0, max_latitude=84.0)}, figsize=(10, 7))

ax.coastlines()
ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, edgecolor='green', linestyle='--')

# save the picture
filename = 'world.png'
fig.savefig(filename)

# USA world view
with Image(filename=filename) as img:
    # make the map center bulgy
    img.virtual_pixel = 'transparent'
    img.implode(-2, 'mesh')
    # place text somewhere in the middle
    width, height = img.size
    with Drawing() as ctx:
        ctx.font_family = 'Arial'
        ctx.font_size = 40
        img.annotate('USA', ctx, left=round(width/2), baseline=round(height/2))
    # save the picture
    img.save(filename='usa_world.png')
```

First, this code will produce the following image:

[image]

and then the distorted one looking like this:

[image]

Alternatively, you could try to make a Cartopy map having [Nearside Perspective projection](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/reference/projections.html#nearsideperspective) with a relatively low satellite height:

```py
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.feature as cfeature

# globe with the US in front
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.NearsidePerspective(central_longitude=-95, central_latitude=40, satellite_height=1000000))
ax.stock_img()
ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, linestyle=':')
plt.show()
```

The code will procude an image, which could probably make an impression of the target area occupying at least half of the globe:

[image]